# Run node js server in ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, nodejs

I have tried so far installed node.js and npm via

`sudo apt-get install nodejs`  and `sudo apt-get install npm` . Then I tried typing node on bash nothing happens, I tried using `node app.js` nothing happens to no error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From our discussion [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

After installing `node.js` and `npm`

Create a symbolic link for node:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Now verify commands working with

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Run it by using,

`node hello.js`

In order to test the application, open another terminal session and connect to your web server. Be sure to substitute in the app server's private IP address for APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS, and the port if you changed it:

`curl http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:8080`

reference [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to install one more package to get the links all working:

`sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

This was explained and answered in detail already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168141/can-not-install-packages-using-node-package-manager-in-ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

The `node` package that you installed when you ran `sudo apt-get install node` is not actually NodeJS. Instead, the `node` package actually predates NodeJS and installs [Amateur Packet Radio](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/node).

The package you are looking for is actually `nodejs`. However, installing `nodejs` on Ubuntu will give you an outdated version of NodeJS. Alternatively, you can install NodeJS using a PPA or from Node Version Manager (nvm).

I've posted a [comparison of the different installation methods with pros and cons](https://askubuntu.com/a/627111/2079). My personal preference when installing Node on an Ubuntu development machine is to [install using NVM](https://askubuntu.com/a/531943/2079). If you're installing NodeJS on a production server, you'll be better off following [instructions from Nodesource](https://askubuntu.com/a/673033/2079).